# Connection String in a VB.NET Application

Tags: vb.net

I used to work only with asp.net websites before. I know that in ASP.NET website, the connection string is found in the web.config file.

My problem is now I have started working with VB.NET applications which needed to be interfaced to a database. How is a connection string created and where should I put it?

Thanks!

Here's the whole app.config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration> 
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbAsthmaConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=9300-00\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbStore;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=johnsmith;Password=1234" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <!-- This section defines the logging configuration for My.Application.Log -->
      <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
         <listeners>
           <add name="FileLog"/>
             <!-- Uncomment the below section to write to the Application Event Log -->
             <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
         </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="FileLog"
           type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" 
           initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
      <!-- Uncomment the below section and replace APPLICATION_NAME with the name of your application to write to the Application Event Log -->
      <!--<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="APPLICATION_NAME"/> -->
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok here is an axample :
1- Your app.config should look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Amlakconn" connectionString ="Data Source=KHASHAYAR-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Amlak;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

2- and in your code you can access the connectionsttring this way :

```
private string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Amlakconn"].ConnectionString;
```

go try It ;)

Answer (score 2):

The other answers tell you where to put the connection string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.80).aspx

This is the easiest way to create a Connection String.

a) Create a Text file, rename the extension from TXT to UDL, press enter.

b) Double click the UDL file and choose OLEDB Provider For SQL Server > Next > type the Database Server name > Select the database and click Test Connection.

[image]

c) When the Test passes, close the UDL file and open it with notepad, the bold lines are the connection string:

[oledb]
; Everything after this line is an OLE DB initstring
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;**Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Data Source=SQLEXPRESS**

Answer (score 0):

Non ASP.NET application can also use config file, it is just not named `web.config`. This file has exactly the same structure you know from ASP.NET including `ConnectionStrings` section. You can copy content from `web.config` and paste sections you need into `app.config`. In project it will show as `app.config` but in the bin folder it is named after the executable file name (with exe extension) plus ".config".

To create this file, go to project's `Add -> New Item` and select Application Configuration File. To get access to your connection strings create/copy `<ConnectionString>` section into `<configuration>` section and then use this code:

```
string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStringName"].ConnectionString;
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Users", conStr);
```

You need to add reference to `System.Configuration' assembly.

Comment: Thanks but when I tried to create a table adapter, the connection string didn't show up. I placed the connection string inside <configuration></configuration>

Comment: Just copy and paste the whole <ConnectionStrings> section from your web.confg.

Comment: Under which section of the app.config file should I paste it in? There is <configuration>, <system.diagnostics>, etc...

Comment: Updated my answer with more details on how to do it.

Comment: Hi, my connection string looks like this and here is what I pasted in the <ConnectionString>: <add name="dbAsthmaConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=9300-00\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbStore;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=johnsmith;Password=1234" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: You need to paste the WHOLE <connectionStrings> section including its opening and closing tags.

Comment: Done that. I am trying to create a table adapter in a dataset but the connection string still does not appear on the list. I don't think it reads it... I have included the whole app.config file in the question.

Comment: You need to use the code I have you to read the connection string and use it when creating connection object.

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't show "<configuration> and </configuration>". Anyway, they are before the <connectionStrings> and after the </system.diagnostics>.

Comment: All right but how do I use your code in creating a tableadapter? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a webapp project It's the same ! you can put that in the web.config file , and if you project is win app you can add an app.config file to your project and pu the connection string in there !

Comment: What I did was I copied everything in my web.config file which perfectly works to the app.config file. However, when I tried to add a table adapter, it doesn't see the connection string. What could be the mistake?

Comment: I posted you a sample source code on how to write the connectionstring in app.config file and how to use that in your code behind ! did you use that ?!